# Integrar rama a develop y seguir trabajando funcionalidades adicionales en la rama para integrarlas posteriormente a develop

Tags: git, git-merge

He realizado un nuevo modulo en una rama **B** que no quiero cerrar aun ya que le faltan funcionalidades, sin embargo quiero integrar a la rama **develop** lo que ya esta en esa rama **B**

```
git checkout develop
git merge B
```

En este momento **B** y **develop** son iguales, pero si sigo trabajando en la rama **B** para agregar la funcionalidad restante que pasa cuando yo quiera integrar de nueva cuenta la rama **B** a **develop** con los comandos arriba mencionados?

Es una buena practica o como recomiendan que integre la funcionalidad de un modulo pero que pueda seguir trabajando en mas funcionalidades?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Una funcionalidad por rama? ¿O te cobran por crear ramas? El review de los cambios para la MR de esa *mega* rama multi funcionalidades será algo largo.

Comment: No pasaría nada fuera de lo normal. Git mezclaría los cambios que haya en B posteriores a la vez anterior en la que hiciste el merge de B hacia develop. Ahora bien, como indica @MauricioContreras Hacer reviews de ramas largas es un infierno. Es preferible ir mezclando cambios más pequeños (como features).... pero técnicamente es posible manejarlo como ramas largas, para git no hace diferencia si una rama tiene 2 commits o 1000 a la hora de hacer un merge.